# Renaming a directory - creates a new (empty) on

Tags: php, directory, rename

I'm trying to rename a directory:

```
rename("billeder/123", "billeder/abc");
```

Immediately thereafter I modify the content of a file within the directory:

```
$s = file_get_contents("billeder/abc/fil.txt");  // note: using the new directory name (abc)!  
$s = str_replace( "123", "abc", $s);  
file_put_contents("billeder/abc/fil.txt", $s);
```

The result is weird: The file content gets modified, OK!
- but it still sits in the old directory (`123`), and a new empty directory is created (`abc`) ?!?!

PS:

- The directory is_writable()
- I'm on a linux-server (Ubuntu, everything is up-to-date)
- I've tried using the full paths in rename() - no difference.
- I've tried adding a / at the end of the names - no difference.
- I've tried modifying the file first, before renaming the dir - still no difference.

Getting desperate.. Can anyone figure out what's going on ?

Comment: This may have to do with PHP's internal caching when dealing with files. Try http://tw.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shucks - my fault (again) - It works as expected.

Cause (as if anybody cares): (re)Extracted the content of a zip-file (too much).. It's complicated..
- and misread abc/123 - they're actually 16-digit numbers, that **look alike** : )
I owe everybody a beer!

Comment: I gave u a plus 1 cause I smiled at your last sentence, not because this helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "*" from the names.

Comment: Those aren't mine - Till Helge Helwig is trying to clarify my question, I think..?

Comment: Nope: just billeder/123 and billeder/abc